# Does anyone know solution for adding pure javascript filter for View?

Tags: 7, views, javascript

As in queston. I was googling and searching forum, but found nothing useful.

I want to setup dynamic filter for a view. Eg. http://silverwareconsulting.com/index.cfm/2008/10/2/jquery-autofiltering-table. One difference is that I need to take filter value from textfield.

Maybe this functionality is built-in in Views, but I missed that?

Comment: Please add more information. What view is it? What filter value?

Comment: Any available filter. Eg. textfield for filtering results by selected view field, eg. first name. View format probably will be Table, but I found that similar solution is more flexible and exists in Drupal world

Answer (score 0):

I'ld suggest you choose views format `Table` and then add your JS from `hook_page_build()`.